# select an xml object based on piece of deeplink property

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, filtering

I'm developing a page using an xml file to print on screen. Now I need to print only objects that have a starting piece of url into  property like this:

```
<product zupid="d490dd40f6dbaf238f28b57abad92fbf">
     <deepLink>http://ad.zanox.com/ppc/?28132512C86846042&amp;ULP=[[offerte-viaggi/vacanze/sconti-triton-villas-residence-hotel-calabria.html]]</deepLink>
</product>
```

Now I'm parsing all because I use this function:

```
for ($i=$offset; $i<$limit+$offset; $i++) { 
     $article=$xml->product[$i];
     $link = $article->deepLink;

     echo "<a target='_blank' href='$link'>Go to link</a>";
}
```

How can I select only object with that part of property/url?

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleXMLElement::xpath() method allows you to use xpath expressions to get an array of elements:

```
$documentElement = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$offset = 1;
$count = 2;

$expression = '//product
  [starts-with(deepLink, "http://ad.zanox.com/")]
  [position() >= '.$offset.' and position() < '.($offset + $count).']
';

foreach ($documentElement->xpath($expression) as $product) {
  var_dump((string)$product->deepLink);
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/162300

About the expression:

Select all `product` elements in die document ...

`//product`

... if the deepLink element as text start with a given string

`//product
  [starts-with(deepLink, "http://ad.zanox.com/")]`

Limit the list of found nodes with an minimum and maximum

`//product
  [starts-with(deepLink, "http://ad.zanox.com/")]
  [position() >= 1 and position() < 3`]`

**HINT**: Positions in Xpath start with 1, not with 0.

Comment: thanks for your help. My problem is to take only this piece of url-> http://ad.zanox.com/ppc/?28132512C86846042&amp;ULP=[[offerte-viaggi but after changing your example it doesn't go. Why? 
Another question is how can I load an external xml file and not an xml written in the same file?
If I use this -> $documentElement = new SimpleXMLElement('testing.xml'); don't load nothing. Why?

Comment: Please set the url example in backticks, SO will format it otherwise. For loading XML from a file with SimpleXML the [simplexml_load_file() function](http://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file) can be used.

Comment: Be careful with escaping in the url. It is `&amp;` in XML/HTML but just `&` in Xpath (the parser decodes the entities).